# OpenShift: Cannot stop, restart or remove application after cartridge add

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

I tried to add a cartridge (cron-1.4) to an existing OpenShift application and it locked without giving me the possibility to stop, restart or remove it. I also tried to connect with ssh using rhc shell but it fails to connect. I tried the command

```
rhc app force-stop
```

but nothing change. This is the error that it reports:

```
Shell command '/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 548b075ce0b8cdcf8c0000e3 -c "exec /usr/bin/runcon 'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c5,c854' /bin/sh -c \"/var/lib/openshift/548b075ce0b8cdcf8c0000e3/cron/bin/setup --version 1.4\""' returned an error. rc=254
Resources unavailable for operation. You may need to run 'rhc force-stop-app -a events' and retry.
/var/lib/openshift/548b075ce0b8cdcf8c0000e3/cron/bin/setup: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/var/lib/openshift/548b075ce0b8cdcf8c0000e3/cron/bin/setup: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/var/lib/openshift/548b075ce0b8cdcf8c0000e3/cron/bin/setup: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/var/lib/openshift/548b075ce0b8cdcf8c0000e3/cron/bin/setup: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/var/lib/openshift/548b075ce0b8cdcf8c0000e3/cron/bin/setup: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: have you tried `rhc force-stop-app -a event`as requested in the error log?

Comment: Yes, I tried `rhc force-stop-app -a events`. I also tried `rhc cartridge remove cron-1.4 -a events` but it shows me the same error log.